# MySql find only Users who are visiting one and not multiple cities

Tags: mysql, unique

I have a table with user_ids, cities and booking dates. I need to find out which users have visited only one city and not multiple cities within a date range.

```
SELECT 
user_id, 
city, 
COUNT(*) as result 
FROM visits
WHERE start_ts >= 1675209600 -- 1675209600 = 01.02.2023 00:00
AND end_ts <= 1676419200 -- 1676419200 = 15.2.2023 00:00
GROUP BY user_id, city
```

| user_id | city | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Munich | 1 |
| 11 | Barcelona | 2 |
| 11 | Berlin | 1 |
| 12 | Barcelona | 1 |
| 13 | Prague | 2 |
| 11 | Barcelona | 1 |
| 13 | Berlin | 1 |

User ID 10 and 12 visited only one city. For example User ID 11 visited Barcelona twice.

I tried with NOT EXISTING and INNER JOIN. How can I get only Users who visited only one city.

Comment: after `GROUP BY` you can filter the results using `HAVING`, for example `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`

Comment: Thanks it's working: 
 SELECT v.user_id,v.city
 FROM visits v
 JOIN visits c 
 ON v.user_id=c.user_id
 WHERE v.user_id IN
 (SELECT v.user_id FROM visits v GROUP BY v.user_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)

Answer (score 0):

Add `HAVING` to your query:

```
SELECT user_id, city, COUNT(*) as result
FROM visits 
WHERE start_ts >= 1675209600 -- 1675209600 = 01.02.2023 00:00
AND end_ts <= 1676419200 -- 1676419200 = 15.2.2023 00:00
GROUP BY user_id, city
HAVING result = 1
```

if you need to count only the unique cities, you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT(city))` and remove it from the grouping, like this:

```
SELECT user_id, city, COUNT(DISTINCT(city)) as result
FROM visits 
WHERE start_ts >= 1675209600 -- 1675209600 = 01.02.2023 00:00
AND end_ts <= 1676419200 -- 1676419200 = 15.2.2023 00:00
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING result = 1
```

Comment: This gives me one time visits for every user_id. User_id 11 was in Berlin and Barcelona. I need to know which user was only in city and not in other cities.

Comment: in this case you should group it only by user_id (without city)

Comment: you can also- count duplicate city as 1 by writing `COUNT(DISTINCT(city))` - so if a user visited multiple times the same city, it will be counted as one time